# Struts2 checkboxlist sends duplicate values for selected values

Tags: java, user-interface, struts2

I am using struts2 checkboxlist.

JSP code:

```
    <s:checkboxlist id="selectedOperators" labelposition="left" 
name="selectedOperators.operatorId" theme="vertical-checkbox" 
list="operators" value="selectedOperators.{operatorId}"  listValue="operatorName"        listKey="operatorId"  />
```

Action Class bindings :

```
 private Collection<OperatorDTO> operators = new ArrayList<>();
 private Collection<OperatorDTO> selectedOperators = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now when i submit my jsp page by selecting only 2 checkboxes. I see 4 values in my selectedOperators list. Those two selected entries are duplicated.

Both the collections are empty before submitting the JSP page.

Can someone please let me know what wrong i am doing.

Thank in advance.

Comment: How many values were in your selectedOperators before you submitted your JSP?

Comment: Change your `selectedOperators` collection from `OperatorDTO` to `operatorId` type.